# Keeping aspect ratio and autolayout for different devices

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, xcode8

I have labels and toolbars on the top and bottom of the screen with height constraints. And I got UIImage between toolbars. So toolbars and labels are keeping same height for different devices while space between toolbars is changeable. 
My goal is to keep aspect ratio 1:1 for devices from SE to IPad and to center UIImage between toolbars by stretching it until it reach superview margins on sides or toolbars on top and bottom. I was tried different approaches but the best thing I could get is on below screenshot.

[image]

It's keeping aspect ratio but I can't figure out how to keep it centered between toolbars.

**Constraints for UIImage:**

[image]

Since I'm working on iOS 8 supported app I didn't use UIStackView and try to find a solution with constraints only.

Comment: See below the **Bottom space to: toolbar** there is symbol `>=`. Change it on clicking on it by this `=`. And check the output.

Comment: @agent_stack Yes, I tried that but in that case image lose aspect ratio and stretching to bounds

Comment: Remove 1:1 ratio and keep `=` relationship. Keep mind bottom constant must be `0`

Comment: I know but image should stay square like on screenshot above. If I put `=` it will stretch to margins and lose aspect ratio 1:1.

Comment: Then what you want?

Comment: ok. let me explain in dimensions. On SE I got 320x320 image and it will fill the whole space between toolbars. On 7 image will be stretched to 375x375 by aspect ratio constraint. But space between toolbars will raise to 419. So I need to keep that image in the center of that space, not to be clipped to the top constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to do following things :**

1. Add a new view (says, centerView) in between the yellow and green view and give it clear color and give below constraints

   - Leading, trailing to superview as constant = 0.
   - Top to yellow view as constant = 0
   - Bottom to yellow view as constant = 0
2. Now in centerView add ImageView which have Apple logo and give below constraints.

   - Give it fixed height as you want.
   - give it vertically and horizontally centered w.r.t. its superView.

Comment: @Pavel You'r asking me or teling me what you have done ? :/ :/ :/

Comment: Sorry, bad editing :) Well. I just did it and finally works as it should. So what I've done: 1. Add view and set leading and trailing constraints to superview and top and bottom to toolbars. 2. Move UIImage as subview to the view and set following constraints: align X and Y to superview, leading, trailing, top, bottom to the superview with '>=' constants, and finally add aspect ratio 1:1. Now it works well on any device!

Comment: Still exciting how to reach that without adding the view because in that case I cannot use Align Y constraint since image is not in the vertical center of main superview

Comment: Actually after adding the view it makes to change your superview. So now you work with the new frame whose bound is in between the yellow and green view. Hope my answer helps you.

Comment: For best practice for UI Design you have divide the UI and have to deal with it accordingly so that you can manage the components properly otherwise your all components got merged on each other like as it is happening here.

Comment: Yes, I know. I was tried to use extra view before but messed around with constraints. I just think that this view is kinda redundant element that is used only as a container for another view. But for now it is best decision

Comment: It is not actually redundant. It just to separate your components from others. You always have to do this to make UI better.